# get hostname from string using bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

In my bash script I need to extract all hostnames from output of command for further ping:

```
for host in `echo $MXrecords | awk '{ printf "%s", $0; }'` ; do
    ping -c1 $host 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
        answ="OK"
    else
        answ="BAD"
    fi

    echo "\t$host [$answ]" 
done
```

But I have some extra string:

```
40 [BAD]
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. [OK]
30 [BAD]
alt3.aspmx.l.google.com. [OK]
```

I get var MXrecords by means of dig:

```
MXrecords=`dig @$DNSserver $domainName IN MX +short +multiline | awk '{ printf "\t%s\n", $0; }'`
```

Comment: It would be useful if you showed us what is the value in `$MXrecords`

Comment: Example, 10 mx1.parallels.com. 20 mx2.parallels.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output it looks like `$MXrecords` contains the MX records including their priority:

```
40 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Try replacing this:

```
`echo $MXrecords | awk '{ printf "%s", $0; }'`
```

with this:

```
$(echo "$MXrecords" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
for host in ${MXrecords##* }; do
    if ping -c1 $host &>/dev/null; then
        answ="OK"
    else
        answ="BAD"
    fi

    echo "\t$host [$answ]" 
done
```

### Note

- `${MXrecords##* }` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) bash trick (a buil-tin)
- `&>/dev/null` is a bash shorthand for `>/dev/null 2>&1`
- The backquote (`` ` ``) is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082
- no need to test the special variable `$?`, you can use *boolean logic* like I do in my snippet

Comment: Unfortunately, it also leaves the same extra lines.